# Securing a bookshelf to a shared (concrete?) townhouse wall

Tags: concrete, walls, hanging

I just rented a townhouse and the shared walls must be concrete or something equally hard. I have two large connected bookcases and had them anchored (to prevent tipover) to a stud in my previous house. If I drill into this wall, how I can repair the holes when moving out? What is the counterpart to spackle on drywall? And am I right in suspecting that it will be very difficult to make a seamless, undetectable repair?

Edit: image attached. The walls look like painted drywall, essentially, it's only when you rap on them that you realize they are rockhard.
[image]

Comment: There's a bare concrete wall? Is it painted? Textured? To get credible answers if the texture/color/etc. can be reproduced, you ought to supply a picture. I suggest putting a coin, pencil, or some other commonly recognizable item in such a picture for scale.

Comment: Attached image for reference, thx.

Comment: Making an undetectable repair in _any_ wall surface is difficult. However, _most_ landlords will give you a pass on small holes for mounting things so long as you're not excessive about it. Check your rental agreement or just talk to the landlord about what's acceptable damage for mounting things to the wall. You may find that for _this_ wall _no_ damage is acceptable, while she's fine with mounting holes elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried drilling into it yet? It might just be 2x layers of 5/8" drywall. Try drilling a small hole, 1/16" and see what it does...does it bottom out and not go in..

Comment: what's wrong with drilling into concrete? (is that poured concrete or cinder blocks? Can you just repaint the whole wall when moving out?

Comment: Paint usually won't gap the kind of hole that is necessary for mounting most things to a wall, @njzk2, therefore, something has to fill the hole, then the paint can cover the filler.

Comment: @FreeMan sure, I meant fill the whole and paint over, filling a bookcase anchoring hole is the easy part in re-painting the whole thing

Answer (score 2):

On a painted wall like that plaster filler will work just as well as it does on drywall.  I would go with the powdered stuff as it sets up faster.

So just drill holes and use concrete anchors, pick a type that does not leave a stud protruding from the wall when you remove your book case. eg: wall plugs, or the expanding nut type of concrete anchor.

Answer (score 0):

There's less leverage at the shelf's base for fasteners to fight overturning, but anchoring down to the floor is an alternative depending on the floor material.

For the wall, that nice closed surface looks very patch-able. Sand the hole edges a bit so there isn't a high ridge around the hole's perimeter. Use the spackle. Dab the surface with a damp (barely wet) sponge to get similar texture. Remember that as the spackle sets up, the sponge's texture will get more and more muted. If the texture is initially too rough, then, wait for it to harden up a little and try again. It won't be perfect, but paint will eventually hide it (with enough coats).